# Replacement default browser application Instead the WebView in android when I use the header("Location:filename.php")

Tags: php, android, webview

The following code works well when I have only one `php` file in my server. As the result when the server responses to the android, the `WebView` widget is in steady State on the screen. first, Please see the my code that it is correct:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //WebView Object
        WebView browser;
        browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        //Enable Javascript
        browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //Inject WebAppInterface methods into Web page by having Interface name 'Android'
        browser.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
        //Load URL inside WebView
        String s = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/apps/webview.php";
        browser.loadUrl(s);
    }
    public class WebAppInterface {
        Context mContext;

        /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
        WebAppInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        /**
         * Show Toast Message
         * @param toast
         */
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void showToast(String toast) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Now, Please see the following `php` code that it is correct:

```
 <?php
echo "hello";
echo '<script> Android.showToast("Hello") </script>';
?>
```

When I run the above code, the `WebView` widget is in steady State on the screen and I can see the `Hello` text using the `Toast` on the screen.

The problem starts when I change above `php` code as follows:

```
<?php
echo "hello";
header("Location:welcom.php");
?>
```

And then I add another `php` code that its name is `welcome` and it is as follows:

```
<?php

echo '<script> Android.showToast("Welcome") </script>';

?>
```

Now, when I run the code in my device, first, when it does the redirect operations to the `welcome.php` file, Suddenly, the `WebView`widget disappears and the default browser application opens on the screen, as the result I can not see the `echo '<script> Android.showToast("Welcome") </script>';` in my device screen and also on the `WebView` widget.

Answer (score 0):

I succeeded to solve my problem. I just implement the web client and set it before `loadUrl`.

```
  browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```